# Speed up very slow query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to clean up an old SQLite3 database deleting about 30.000 old records from it.
To delete them I'm using this query:

```
DELETE
FROM
    ITEMS
WHERE
    ITEMS_ID IN (
        SELECT
            ITEMS_ID
        FROM
            ITEMS
        WHERE
            LASTSALEDATE NOT LIKE '2014%'
        AND LASTSALEDATE NOT LIKE '2013%'
        AND LASTSALEDATE NOT LIKE '2012%'
        AND ITEMS_ID != 1
        AND ITEMS_ID != 4
    );
```

The problem is that I've noticed this query is very slow, or better, so slow that it takes ages and I've to abort it because seems stuck.

I think the problem is the `IN()`  inside the `SELECT` statement being repeated for each row deleted.

How can I fix this query?

Comment: why don't you put WHERE strait in DELETE statement?

Comment: I've simplified it a bit, the SELECT is used in more than one table but probably you are right in this case...

Comment: Where lastsaledate < '2012' instead of the 3 not likes might help.

Comment: If you have delete triggers, disable them.

Comment: @jose How can I disable them without delete them?

Comment: @DanBracuk < 2012 doesn't work

Comment: @FezVrasta I am afraid in SqlLite there is no way to "disable a trigger". You have to save the delete trigger script, drop it, run the delete query, then finally open the saved script and reapply the triggers.

Comment: The term "doesn't work" is vague.  Did it throw an error?  Did it produce incorrect results?

Comment: @DanBracuk it just doesn't select anything.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos was actually the solution, may you please post an answer so I can se it as correct? Thanks!

Comment: @FezVrasta Posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before making massive deletions, make sure there are no delete triggers running behind the scenes, that can cause a considerable slow down in the `delete` statement.

I don't think it is possible to temporally disable triggers in SqlLite, as it is in other DBMS. So, you have to:

1. Save the delete trigger scripts
2. Drop the delete trigger(s)
3. Run the delete query
4. Recreate the delete trigger(s)

Also, try to understand what these delete triggers are doing, before disabling them. They might do something important, such data auditing or changes vital to maintain data integrity. In this case, it might be worth to have some patience and wait a little for the deletion be done.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have then `IN` at all?

```
    DELETE
    FROM
        ITEMS
    WHERE
        LASTSALEDATE NOT LIKE '2014%'
    AND LASTSALEDATE NOT LIKE '2013%'
    AND LASTSALEDATE NOT LIKE '2012%'
    AND ITEMS_ID != 1
    AND ITEMS_ID != 4
```

**EDIT :**

Assuming a more complex structure, that you haven't detailed, this may be more efficient than an `IN`...

```
DELETE
  ITEMS
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ITEMS_ID
  FROM
    ITEMS
  WHERE
        LASTSALEDATE NOT LIKE '2014%'
    AND LASTSALEDATE NOT LIKE '2013%'
    AND LASTSALEDATE NOT LIKE '2012%'
    AND ITEMS_ID != 1
    AND ITEMS_ID != 4
  GROUP BY
    ITEMS_ID
)
  AS lookup
WHERE
  lookup.ITEMS_ID = ITEMS.ITEMS_ID
```

Also, depending on the datatype of `LASTSALEDATE`, try this `WHERE` clause.

```
  WHERE
        LASTSALEDATE <  '2012-01-01'
    AND ITEMS_ID     <> 1
    AND ITEMS_ID     <> 4
```

Comment: @FezVrasta : For more detailed feedback, please give a more complete example of the problem query.

Comment: Thanks, LASTSALEDATE is `timestamp`